# Packages or a template for SOP writing

Tags: templates

I'd like to write SOPs with latex (like [this examples](http://templatelab.com/sop-templates/)). Unfortunately I haven't found a SOP package yet. In detail, I want to create a multi-page document, with each page framed from header to footer and structured in tabular form (several columns).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `xltabular` package for structuring  in full width tabulars (the package defines  a tabularx environment breakable along multiple pages).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what are SOPs?

Comment: Sorry for the Delay. SOP stands for Standard Operating Procedure. Standard operating procedures are a central element of quality management. The SOP ensure that employees carry out work processes according to a specific scheme and can therefore comply with or implement the basic principles of ISO 9001.